# Liferay hibernate exception

Tags: java, hibernate, liferay

I need to get all user groups from liferay portal, but `UserGroupServiceUtil` from it's api has only method to get user groups of the specific user. I found method I need in `persistence/UserGroupUtil` - `findAll()`. But when I try to use it, I get an exception:

> No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow
>   creation of non-transactional one here.

I found that I need to write a facade to class with needed method - `*ServiceImpl`.

I don't understand how to do this, could you help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
getUserGroups(long companyId)
```

from UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.

It returns all user groups for specified company. You can get company id from ThemeDisplay from your portlet request.

Comment: As far as I know, company is not required field. We don't use it. So, I need to get all user groups in other way.

Comment: Everything in liferay is connected to some company - look into the database. Usually you have only one company unless you use multiple portal instances on one liferay instance (which i doubt)

Comment: I've created test user, and have empty "organizations" field. If "company" is something else, this might help, but I don't see it from control panel - only organization, communities, etc. Where can I find "company"?

Comment: Company is equal to portal instance (you can see your portal instance in control panel -> server section (bottom) -> portal instances. Every entity in portal (organization, community, user group, ...) belongs to a company and if you look into the database you will see companyId column. But usualy you dont have to worry about that. Just get ThemeDisplay object from your request and you have your current (and as I said usually the only one) company id.

Comment: that's good! thank you! and last question: when portal must have multiple instances?

Comment: You would use multiple instances if you wanted to have two completely separated portal on one physical machine (e.g. for different customers using same application). You can diferentiate between companies using the domain name.

Comment: oh, no, I think, I really have only one instance. Thank you, I understood subject!

Answer (score 0):

you need to create one method inside serviceImpl to call persistence.findall method..

Ex :-

```
    public List<Student>getStudents() throws SystemException{
    return studentPersistence.findAll();
}
```

Comment: but what should I do to create serviceImpl?

Answer (score 0):

seviceImpl class is automatically gets generated when you build the service builder.....

Comment: and where can I find service builder? I'm using netbeans 7.1. I don't see service builder here. Maybe you show me some manual, or any point to start search and to do work?

Answer (score 0):

Its just same as you add liferay portlet into an project.For service builder you need to select liferay service. it will create a service.xml in that u can provide column name which u want in u r database....then bulid service ...all relevant classes will be created automatically.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-7050/ghrxe/index.html

this link will guide u

Comment: I've installed portal pack plugin and found service builder. Thank you for link. It's useful.